# Creating a simple "click thumbnail, change main image" code

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, attr

I'm trying to get the main image to change depending on the thumbnail image clicked. 
I would want the main image to take its new src from the a tag of the thumbnail that was clicked.

I've seen other methods using attr, src but in each case they specify manually the new "src", how could i get the code to take the src from the a tag of the thumbnail clicked?

Would really appreciate if anyone could show me, thanks.

EDIT:

Trying to change the caption of the main photo, getting the new caption from the thumbnail clicked/ My simplified code looks like this

```
         <img src="{hotel_main_photo}" id="main_photo" class="view_page_photo frame"      width="420" height="320" alt="{title}" />

        <p>{main_caption}</p>

        <div id="thumbnails">

            <img src="{thumb}" width ="" height="" alt="" />

                            <p>{thumb_caption}</p>

            {/hotel_other_photos}

        </div>
```

I'm basically trying to change the 'main_caption' to display the thumb_caption of the thumbnail clicked. I could store the thumb_caption as the title or alt if that would help?

Thanks again

EDITED AGAIN(!)

I think using James' suggestion, I've sort of figured it out with the following

$("#main_caption").text($(this).attr("alt"));

Comment: If you can put your code or html in the question it would be much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $("#mainImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

It simply gets the `src` of the clicked `.thumbnail` element and uses it as the `src` value of `#mainImage`.

Comment: Wow that's fantastic thanks! I was worried I'd have to use arrays without understanding them... One small thing, I added return false for the a tags around the images. Thanks so much James!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to change the associated text with it too would you? For example after each thumbnail there is a 'p' tag with the caption. Is there any way of changing the caption at the same time as changing the src so that the thumbs caption becomes the main image's caption?

Comment: Well it's hard to say without knowing your HTML structure, but you should be able to simply do something like `$("#whatever").text("whatever");`. If you need more help with it I suggest posting a new question.

Comment: Can't seem to add code to this comment so will add it as an answer, would really appreciate your thoughts, thanks